# Taking input from cin that's separated by a space and putting into an int array

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

For my program I have to take multiple values on a line and then store them into an int array. The int values are separated by a space. I want to use cin and maybe a for loop but I can't really figure it out.

```
int array_max;

cout << "Input number of values (max. of 100): ";
cin >> array_max;
cout << "Input values: ";
cin >> 

int array[array_max];
```

Not sure what to put in for my cin to store the values into the array. The input should look like this.

```
Input number of values (max. of 100): 4
Input values: 4 10 2 5
```

And then store those values into an array in that order. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that includes the description of `std::getline()`, and read it.

Comment: `int array[array_max];` with non-constant `array_max` is not valid C++, although some compilers accept it as an extension.